# An efficient algorithm to count the number of integer grids

Tags: algorithm, combinatorics

Consider a square 3 by 3 grid of non-negative integers.  For each row `i` the sum of the integers is set to be `r_i`.  Similarly for each column `j` the sum of integers in that column is set to be `c_j`.  An instance of the problem is therefore described by `6` non-negative integers.

> Is there an efficient algorithm to count how many different
>   assignments of integers to the grid there are given the row and column
>   sum constraints?

Clearly one could enumerate all possible matrices of non-negative integers with values up to `sum r_i` and check the constraints for each, but that would be insanely slow.

**Example**

Say the row constraints are `1 2 3` and the column constraints are `3 2 1`. The possible integer grids are:

```
┌─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┐
│0 0 1│0 0 1│0 0 1│0 1 0│0 1 0│0 1 0│0 1 0│1 0 0│1 0 0│1 0 0│1 0 0│1 0 0│
│0 2 0│1 1 0│2 0 0│0 1 1│1 0 1│1 1 0│2 0 0│0 1 1│0 2 0│1 0 1│1 1 0│2 0 0│
│3 0 0│2 1 0│1 2 0│3 0 0│2 1 0│2 0 1│1 1 1│2 1 0│2 0 1│1 2 0│1 1 1│0 2 1│
└─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┘
```

In practice my main interest is when the total sum of the grid will be at most 100 but a more general solution would be very interesting.

Comment: @tobias_k The constraints can be much larger than 10.  I don't know how fast your suggestion would be in the worst case.  I mean even doing one check for all 100^9 possible grids, say, would be too much.

Comment: Ah, sorry, somehow I thought that every cell could only contain a single-digit number. Of course, if each number can get as high as min(nj, cj), then that's not really feasible.

Comment: So basically you have to solve a system of 6 equations with 9 variables, each in the form `0x11 + 0x12 + 0x13 + 1x21 + 1x22 + 1x23 + 0x31 + 0x32 + 0x33 = r2`, where `xij` is the value in the ith row and jth column.

Comment: Assuming you found a single solution, if you selected four entries in a rectangle, such as [(0,0), (0,2), (1,0), (1,2)], you should be able to increase one pair of diagonals by some value, and decrease the other pair by that same value and discover a range of other solutions.

Comment: In a 3x3 grid, there would only be 8 such rectangles possible.  I would suspect that you could determine the size of each range, then multiply all 8 values to get one total.

Comment: Can you add an example, and the expected range of values, just to be sure we're all talking about the same thing?

Comment: @m69 Added now. I hope it helps.

Comment: I missed one.  There are 9 possible rectangles.

Comment: If the total sum is at most 100, and you only have to go through the values for 4 positions and calculate the 5 others, then surely this won't be "insanely slow"?

Comment: @m69 That's interesting. Could you spell that out a little more please.

Comment: @eleanora Well, if you know the sum for each row and column, you only need the top 2x2 numbers, the rest results directly from the row/column sums. But where does the upper limit of 100 come from all of a sudden?

Comment: Indeed. Have you timed a simple 4-nested-loop solution to see whether it actually needs optimizing?

Comment: @tobias_k Thanks!  I was just thinking of how big a problem I might actually care about. I will try that (and @m69).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It won't help with the problem being #P-hard (if you allow matrices to be of any sizes -- see reference in the comment below), but there is a solution which doesn't amount to enumerate all the matrices but rather a smaller set of objects called [semi-standard Young tableaux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semistandard_Young_tableaux). Depending on your input, it could go faster, but still being of exponential complexity. Since it's an entire chapter in several algebraic combinatorics book or in Knuth's AOCP 3, I won't go into details here only pointing to the relevant wikipedia pages.

The idea is that using the [Robinson–Schensted–Knuth correspondence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robinson%E2%80%93Schensted%E2%80%93Knuth_correspondence) each of these matrix is in bijection with a pair of tableaux of the same shape, where one of the tableau is filled with integers counted by the row sum, the other by the column sum. The number of tableau of shape U filled with numbers counted by V is called the [Kostka Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kostka_number) K(U,V). As a consequence, you end up with a formula such as

```
#Mat(RowSum, ColSum) = \sum_shape  K(shape, RowSum)*K(shape, ColSum)
```

Of course if RowSum == ColSum == Sum:

```
#Mat(Sum, Sum) = \sum_shape  K(shape, Sum)^2
```

Here is your example in the SageMath system:

```
sage: sum(SemistandardTableaux(p, [3,2,1]).cardinality()^2 for p in  Partitions(6))
12
```

Here are some larger examples:

```
sage: sums = [6,5,4,3,2,1]
sage: %time sum(SemistandardTableaux(p, sums).cardinality()^2 for p in Partitions(sum(sums)))
CPU times: user 228 ms, sys: 4.77 ms, total: 233 ms
Wall time: 224 ms
8264346

sage: sums = [7,6,5,4,3,2,1]
sage: %time sum(SemistandardTableaux(p, sums).cardinality()^2 for p in Partitions(sum(sums)))
CPU times: user 1.95 s, sys: 205 µs, total: 1.95 s
Wall time: 1.94 s
13150070522

sage: sums = [5,4,4,4,4,3,2,1]
sage: %time sum(SemistandardTableaux(p, sums).cardinality()^2 for p in Partitions(sum(sums)))
CPU times: user 1.62 s, sys: 221 µs, total: 1.62 s
Wall time: 1.61 s
1769107201498
```

It's clear that you won't get that fast enumerating matrices.

As requested by  גלעד ברקן@ here is a solution with different row and column sums:

```
sage: rsums = [5,4,3,2,1]; colsums = [5,4,3,3]
sage: %time sum(SemistandardTableaux(p, rsums).cardinality() * SemistandardTableaux(p, colsums).cardinality() for p in Partitions(sum(rsums)))
CPU times: user 88.3 ms, sys: 8.04 ms, total: 96.3 ms
Wall time: 92.4 ms
10233
```

Comment: The problem is in P so can't be #P hard.

Comment: It is #P hard if you allow matrix to be as large as possible. See my examples.

Comment: Interesting. Do you have a proof for that?

Comment: See the reference in Wikipedia eg: Knuth's AOCP3. There is a paper around those question https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0501176 where it cites  M. Dyer, R. Kannan and J. Mount, Sampling Contingency tables, Random Structures and Algorithms, (1979) 10 487-506 for the complexity of couting matrices by row/col sums

Comment: Thank you for a very interesting answer. Does the time and space for construction of the `SemistandardTableaux` depend on the actual values in the arrays passed as arguments (as opposed to merely the arrays' length)?

Comment: This is a fascinating and surprising answer. I would also love to understand the complexity more for the 3 by 3 case.  What do you think it is exactly?

Comment: Can you please post a Sage Math example where the row sums are different than the column sums?

Comment: @eleanora: for the 3x3 problem, I'm pretty sure one can find some kind of a closed formula. I'll post another answer if I find one.

Comment: That would be awesome!

Answer (score 5):

> Is there an efficient algorithm to count how many different assignments of integers to the grid there are given the row and column sum constraints?

**upd** My answer is wrong for this particular problem, when `N` is fixed (i.e. becomes constant `3`). In this case it is polynomial. Sorry for misleading information.

**TL;DR**: I think it's at least NP-hard. There is no polinomial algorithm, but maybe there're some heuristic speedups.

---

For N-by-N grid you have `N` equations for row sums, `N` equations for col sums and `N^2` non-negative constraints :

[image]

For `N > 2` this system has more than one possible solution in general. Because there're `N^2` unknown variables `x_ij` and just `2N` equations => for `N > 2`: `N^2 > 2N`.

You can eliminate `2N - 1` variables to leave with just one equation with `K = N^2 - (2N-1)` variables getting the sum `S`. Then you'll have to deal with [integer partition problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)#Restricted_part_size_or_number_of_parts) to find out all possible combinations of `K` terms to get the `S`. This problem is NP-complete. And the number of combinations depends not only on the number of terms `K`, but also on the order of the value `S`.

This problem reminded me about [Simplex method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex_algorithm). My first thought was to find just one solution using something like that method and then traverse edges of the convex to find all the possible solutions. And I was hoping that there's an optimal algorithm for that. But no, integer simplex method, which is related to [integer linear programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming), is NP-hard :(

I hope, there're some kind heuristics for related problems you can use to speedup naive brute force solution.

Comment: N = 3 in my case. So I don't think it makes sense to say it is NP-complete unless you use the size of the constraints as the key parameter.  Does your reduction still work?

Comment: @eleanora so long as `3 > 2` I think it still do. You have to find all possible combination of 9 - (2*3-1) = 4 integer variables to get the known sum.

Comment: The output is just a single number (that is the count of the number of different grids) so it would be very interesting if there really were a reduction from subset sum.  I don't see it from your argument yet.

Comment: I may be totally wrong as being not very experienced in that particular area. So, please, don't trust my answer. I just hope I gave you right links and the directions to dig further.

Comment: As for your last comment. Look at this article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)#Restricted_part_size_or_number_of_parts. It contains the right recurrent equation to get the number.

Comment: The problem is that the NP-hardness here depends not only on `N` (which is small), but also on the sums of rows/cols. Higher numbers, exponentially higher the number of possible grids.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, the naive algorithm is polynomial time in the size of the largest constraint, so it can't be NP-hard.

Comment: yeah, if we fix `N`, the size of grid, then it becomes polynomial.4 variables => `O(largestConstraint ^ 4)`. My mistake :(

Comment: `O(largestConstraint ^ 4)` is generally not considered polynomial because `largestConstraint` is normally `2^input_length` as input may be binary

Comment: @RiaD, generally, yes! I assumed though that the input is bounded from above, e.g. it's 32-bit or 64-bit value.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know of a matching algorithm, but I don't think it would be that difficult to work one out.  Given any one solution, you can derive another solution by selecting four corners of a rectangular region of your grid, increasing two diagonal corners by some value and decreasing the other two by that same value.  The range for that value will be constrained by the lowest value of each diagonal pair.  If you determine the size of all such ranges, you should be able to multiply them together to determine the total possible solutions.

Assuming you described your grid like a familiar spreadsheet alphabetically for columns, and numerically for rows, you could describe all possible regions in the following list:

`A1:B2, A1:B3, A1:C2, A1:C3, B1:C2, B1:C3, A2:B3, A2:C3, B2:C3`

For each region, we tabulate a range based on the lowest value from each diagonal corner pair.  You can incrementally reduce either pair until a member reaches zero because there's no upper bound for the other pair.

Selecting the first solution of your example, we can derive all other possible solutions using this technique.

```
   A B C
  ┌─────┐
1 │0 0 1│ sum=1
2 │0 2 0│ sum=2
3 │3 0 0│ sum=3
  └─────┘
   3 2 1 = sums

A1:B2 - 1 solution (0,0,0,2)
A1:C2 - 1 solution (0,1,0,0)
A1:B3   1 solution (0,0,3,0)
A1:C3   2 solutions (0,1,3,0), (1,0,2,1)
B1:C2   2 solutions (0,1,2,0), (1,0,1,1)
B1:C3   1 solution (0,1,0,0)
A2:B3   3 solutions (0,2,3,0), (1,1,2,1), (2,0,1,2)
A2:C3   1 solution (0,0,3,0)
B2:C3   1 solution (2,0,0,0)
```

Multiply all solution counts together and you get 2*2*3=12 solutions.

Comment: Very interesting. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Maybe a simple 4-nested-loop solution is fast enough, if the total sum is small?

```js
function solve(rowsum, colsum) {
    var count = 0;
    for (var a = 0; a <= rowsum[0] && a <= colsum[0]; a++) {
        for (var b = 0; b <= rowsum[0] - a && b <= colsum[1]; b++) {
            var c = rowsum[0] - a - b;
            for (var d = 0; d <= rowsum[1] && d <= colsum[0] - a; d++) {
                var g = colsum[0] - a - d;
                for (var e = 0; e <= rowsum[1] - d && e <= colsum[1] - b; e++) {
                    var f = rowsum[1] - d - e;
                    var h = colsum[1] - b - e;
                    var i = rowsum[2] - g - h;
                    if (i >= 0 && i == colsum[2] - c - f) ++count;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}
document.write(solve([1,2,3],[3,2,1]) + "<br>");
document.write(solve([22,33,44],[30,40,29]) + "<br>");
```

Answer (score 2):

I've tired to optimize the slow option. I get the all combinations and change the code only to get the total count. This is the fastest I could get:

```
    private static int count(int[] rowSums, int[] colSums)
    {
        int count = 0;
        int[] row0 = new int[3];
        int sum = rowSums[0];
        for (int r0 = 0; r0 <= sum; r0++)
            for (int r1 = 0, max1 = sum - r0; r1 <= max1; r1++)
            {
                row0[0] = r0;
                row0[1] = r1;
                row0[2] = sum - r0 - r1;
                count += getCombinations(rowSums[1], row0, colSums);
            }                    
        return count;
    }
    private static int getCombinations(int sum, int[] row0, int[] colSums)
    {
        int count = 0;
        int max1 = Math.Min(colSums[1] - row0[1], sum);
        int max2 = Math.Min(colSums[2] - row0[2], sum);
        for (int r0 = 0, max0 = Math.Min(colSums[0] - row0[0], sum); r0 <= max0; r0++)
            for (int r1 = 0; r1 <= max1; r1++)
            {
                int r01 = r0 + r1;
                if (r01 <= sum)
                    if ((r01 + max2) >= sum)
                        count++;
            }
        return count;
    }




Stopwatch w2 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
int res = count(new int[] { 1, 2, 3 }, new int[] { 3, 2, 1 });//12
int res1 = count(new int[] { 22, 33, 44 }, new int[] { 30, 40, 29 });//117276
int res2 = count(new int[] { 98, 99, 100}, new int[] { 100, 99, 98});//12743775
int res3 = count(new int[] { 198, 199, 200 }, new int[] { 200, 199, 198 });//201975050
w2.Stop();
Console.WriteLine("w2:" + w2.ElapsedMilliseconds);//322 - 370 on my computer
```

Answer (score 1):

Aside my other answer using Robinson-Schensted-Knuth bijection, here is
another solution which doesn't need advanced combinatorics, but some trick in
programming solve this problem for arbitrary larger matrix. The first idea
that should be used to solve those kind of problems is to use recursion, avoiding recompution things thanks to some memoization
or better dynamic programming. Specifically once you have chosen a candidate
for the first row, you subtract this first row to the column sum and you are
left with the same problem only there is one less row. To avoid recomputing
thing you store the result. You can do this

- either basically in a big table (memoization)
- or in a more tricky way by storing all the solutions for matrices with n rows
  and deducing the number of solutions for matrices with n+1 rows (dynamic programming).

Here is a recursive method using memoization in Python:

```
 # Generator for the rows of sum s which are smaller that maxrow
 def choose_one_row(s, maxrow):
     if not maxrow:
         if s == 0: yield []
         else: return
     else:
         for i in range(0, maxrow[0]+1):
             for res in choose_one_row(s-i, maxrow[1:]):
                 yield [i]+res


 memo = dict()
 def nmat(rsum, colsum):
     # sanity check: sum by row and column must match
     if sum(rsum) != sum(colsum): return 0
     # base case rsum is empty
     if not rsum: return 1
     # convert to immutable tuple for memoization
     rsum = tuple(rsum)
     colsum = tuple(colsum)
     # try if allready computed
     try:
         return memo[rsum, colsum]
     except KeyError:
         pass
     # apply the recursive formula
     res = 0
     for row in choose_one_row(rsum[0], colsum):
         res += nmat(rsum[1:], tuple(a - b for a, b in zip(colsum, row)))
     # memoize the result
     memo[(tuple(rsum), tuple(colsum))] = res
     return res
```

Then after that:

```
sage: nmat([3,2,1], [3,2,1])
12

sage: %time nmat([6,5,4,3,2,1], [6,5,4,3,2,1])
CPU times: user 1.49 s, sys: 7.16 ms, total: 1.5 s
Wall time: 1.48 s
8264346
```